# Curl request works in Rested chrome extension but not in php

Tags: php, curl

everyone, i am requesting data from some other website but I am unable to request through curl it shows error 500 but when I do the same request through chrome RESTED extension it shows me output

```
$url = "XXXXXXXXXXX";

// what post fields?
$fields = array(
    'roll_number' => '123456',
'full_name' => 'aaaaaa',
'mother_name' => 'bbbbbbb',
'_token' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
);

// build the urlencoded data
$postvars = http_build_query($fields);

// open connection


            $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response  = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $response;
```

Request should be by post method and data should be JSON encoded or URL encoded I have tried both but none of them worked

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the cause, but shouldn't your HTTPHEADER be `application/json`? Also, you're not encoding the data as JSON - you might need to change `$postvars = http_build_query($fields);` to `$postvars = json_encode($fields);`

I'd also take a look at https://lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl

Comment: don't work if i change it to application/json and change $postvars to json encode